# Global Styles.css not being applied to components in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

My goal is to apply the following styles throughout my angular site:

```
html, body, app-root, ng-component {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

The above code works, but only because I figured out that I have to add app-root and ng-component... I am wondering why this is necessary.

Shouldn't it just work if I add the styles to html, body? Why do I have to add it to app-root and then ng-component if my application has multiple levels?

In a standard html page if I have a layout that has divs within divs I wouldn't have to add the styles to every div, just the parent container which in this case is html, body...

The Styles.css file that I am referring to is the one in the src directory (the parent of the app directory) when creating a new Angular app w/ Angular CLI.

Comment: where exactly are you adding those styles? in what CSS file and where is that file included ?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam I updated my post at the bottom.

Comment: just added the styles to `styles.css` **without** `app-root, ng-component ` and it works just fine.. I see the font change in the app and in chrome console I see the styles applied to body and HTML. Is there any other styles overriding those?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam it is the height style that is giving me issues. I am using height 100% so I can have a static header and scrollable navbar and content sections. Please see the layout of the Angular Material site: https://material.angular.io/components/component/toolbar

Comment: so this is a pure css issue. You'll have to change your question to something that reflects what your looking to have.The styles are applied appropriately, they are just not the correct styles for your purpose. you might be looking for something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRRRXj